# How to re-tint a grayscale image on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, colors, html5-canvas

Is there any quick way to colorize greyscale icon (png image with transparent background) when drawing it on canvas? By colorize I mean turning greyscale icon into lets say greenscale (shades of given color instead of grey to match given color theme)

I know I could manipulate each pixel manually but maybe there's some more automated way?

Comment: what do you mean, colorize? flood-fill with a color? or turn (say) a B&W picture of person's face into a nice color version with blonde hair/blue eyes?

Comment: sorry, for unclear question, updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use compositing to re-tint a grayscale image into "greenscale".**

Using compositing is faster than pixel manipulation and as a bonus you won't run afoul of cross-domain security restrictions (which you do if you instead used `getImageData`).

1. Create a fully green version of your image.
2. Draw your grayscale image on the canvas.
3. Set `globalCompositeOperation='color'` which causes existing grayscale pixels to be re-tinted ("re-hued") with pixels drawn on top.
4. Draw your fully green image on the canvas.

**"Color" Compositing will turn the grayscale into greenscale.**

[image] + [image] = [image]

*Note: requires a modern browser with blending capabilities (Edge not IE)*

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/koolBW.png";
function start(){

    // create a fully green version of img
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=img.width;
    c.height=img.height;
    cctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
    cctx.fillStyle='green';
    cctx.fillRect(0,0,img.width,img.height);  
    cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';

    // draw the grayscale image onto the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

    // set compositing to color (changes hue with new overwriting colors) 
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='color';

    // draw the fully green img on top of the grayscale image
    // ---- the img is now greenscale ----
    ctx.drawImage(c,0,0);
    
    // Always clean up -- change compositing back to default
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=256 height=256></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using css classes. Check the below example P.S: Source: w3Schools

```css
img {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  max-width: 235px;
}
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
.brightness {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(250%);
  filter: brightness(250%);
}
.contrast {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(180%);
  filter: contrast(180%);
}
.grayscale {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.huerotate {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.invert {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
.opacity {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(50%);
  filter: opacity(50%);
}
.saturate {
  -webkit-filter: saturate(7);
  filter: saturate(7);
}
.sepia {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
  filter: sepia(100%);
}
.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);
  filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The filter property is not supported in Internet Explorer, Edge 12, or Safari 5.1 and earlier.</p>

  <img src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="blur" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="brightness" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="contrast" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="grayscale" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="huerotate" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="invert" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="opacity" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="saturate" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="sepia" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <img class="shadow" src="http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/how_to_draw_medium/public/htd/2015/07/pineapple-0-how-to-draw.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">

</body>
```

Refer this link for learning what filter style can do.

[ClickMe](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)

Comment: I need to export it from canvas to PNG and save on disk so I don't think CSS is an option here

Answer (score 2):

Hey try this alternative!

First create a canvas element and use canvas context to draw image. You can use the canvas filters to apply effects. then use toDataURL method to get the png of the image. All the detailed procedure is explained in the below websites.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-grayscale-image-colors-tutorial/

Finally use .toDataURL() method to export/save it.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: If you're talking about those filters : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter they're unfortunately available only on Firefox. And I'm limited to Chromium (nw.js). I think I'll need to iterate over pixels then :< or try some hacking with blending modes?...

Comment: Yeah! I hope, that's the only way we are left with until someone has a better solution. Good luck!