# color system for tile base game

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-engine

I have started a project to teach myself the mechanics behind tile-base game engines. So far I have a pretty good little demo working but I can't figure out how to implement colors for each tile. I would like for any tile to be any color but this proves to be complicated for me.

the entire game uses 2d arrays for every object/component on the screen. There is a central 2d array that stores all of the walls and floor tiles and anything that's not a separate moving object.
my idea was to have a parallel array that stores color values. Then to iterate and change the color of each tile accordingly.

The base part of my code where I do the actual drawing is in a class called font

```js
class Font{
    constructor(src, tilesizeX, tilesizeY){
        this.fontImage = new Image();
        this.imageBuffer = new Image();
       // this.fontImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '')
        this.fontImage.src = src;
        this.colors = ["#00F","#09f","#fff", "#999"]
        //this.fontImage.onload = this.drawChar();
    }

    drawChar(charCode, posX, posY, color){

        var charmap = [
            [' ','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x','y', 'z', '☺', '☻','♡','♦','♣','♤', '•', '◘', '○', '◙','♂','♀','♪','♫','☼','►','◄','↕','‼','¶','§','▬','↨','↑','↓','→','←','∟','↔','▲','▼',
            '░','▒','▓','│','┤','╡','╢','╖','╕','╣','║','╗','╝','╜','╛','┐',
            '└','┴','┬','├','─','┼','╞','╟','╚','╔','╩','╦','╠','═','╬','╧',
            '╨','╤','╥','╙','╘','╒','╓','╫','╪','┘','┌','█','▄','▌','▐','▀',
            'space', '!','"','#','$','%','&',"'",'(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/',
            '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',':',';','<','=','>','?',
            '@','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
            'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','[','/',']','^','_',
            ],
            [
                [0,0],[6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [6, 10], [6, 11], [6, 12],[6, 13],[6, 14], [6, 15],[7,0],
                [7, 1],[7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [7, 8],[7, 9],[7, 10],
                [0, 1], [0, 2],[0,3], [0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[0,7],[0,8],[0,9],[0,10],[0,11],[0,12],[0,13],[0,14],[0,15],
                [1,0],[1,1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [1, 14], [1, 15],
                
                [11,0],[11,1],[11,2],[11,3],[11,4], [11, 5], [11, 6], [11, 7], [11, 8], [11, 9], [11, 10], [11, 11], [11, 12], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15],
                [12,0],[12,1],[12,2],[12,3],[12,4], [12, 5], [12, 6], [12, 7], [12, 8], [12, 9], [12, 10], [12, 11], [12, 12], [12, 13], [12, 14], [12, 15],
                [13,0],[13,1],[13,2],[13,3],[13,4], [13, 5], [13, 6], [13, 7], [13, 8], [13, 9], [13, 10], [13, 11], [13, 12], [13, 13], [13, 14], [13, 15],
                [2,0],[2,1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13], [2, 14], [2, 15],
                [3,0],[3,1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [3, 10], [3, 11], [3, 12], [3, 13], [3, 14], [3, 15],
                [4,0],[4,1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10], [4, 11], [4, 12], [4, 13], [4, 14], [4, 15],
                [5,0],[5,1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [5, 10], [5, 11], [5, 12], [5, 13], [5, 14], [5, 15],
            ]
        ]

        var scopeX = charmap[1][charmap[0].indexOf(charCode)][1] * 8;
        var scopeY = charmap[1][charmap[0].indexOf(charCode)][0] * 16

        game.ctx.drawImage(this.fontImage, scopeX, scopeY, 7 , 15 , posX, posY, 16, 32);
        

    }
}
```

if I use this code at the end of my `drawChar()` function

```js
game.ctx.drawImage(this.fontImage, scopeX, scopeY, 7, 15, posX, posY, 16, 32);
game.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-out"
game.ctx.fillStyle = this.colors[getRandomInt(0, 3)];
game.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 32);
        
game.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"
```

the first tile is colored as desired but none of the other tiles display. I am still new to all the intricacies of game development and do not know how I should go about adding colors

Comment: You are not doing anything with the ImageData here, so what about you simply remove that code?

Comment: well, I'm rendering from an image I'm just taking a chunk from a central sprite sheet each time I render a tile. the sprite sheet is just an old IBM font as I'm making an ASCII game. I would like to color each image. and using the `imageData` showed some results but not the desired result.

Comment: But here, in the code you shared, the ImageData that is being gotten as `imageData` is never put back to the context, and nothing is ever read from it --> It's not being used, at least not to do anything useful. So... just remove that, in the present snippet you don't need it. (And my gut tells me that you'd prefer use a simple fillRect rather than deal with ImageDatas)

Comment: yeah, I had originally used  `fillRect()` while changing the `globalCompositeOperation` of the context. but that would only work for all of the tiles or just the first or last one. I'm needing different colors for each tile. I'm still new to designing an engine and not sure how to properly handle colors. I have read about using a separate canvas but I'm not sure how that would be for performance either

Comment: Why do you do compositing here? Just set the `fillStyle` of your context if you want to change its color. Small advice, start small to familiarize yourself with the API. Come back later to make a full game engine.

Comment: the canvas API seems simple enough. It's not really a canvas problem that I am having more of an implementation problem. you can see my edit. I can get what I want working but only partly. I have just pinned it down as an implementation problem.

Comment: No offense but given your previous code was doing nothing and you didn't seem to know how to make a colored square, I believe you need to learn more about the API yes. Now, regarding the edit, simply use a second context to do the compositing (once again basic tutorials teach this). As a general rule, it's always good to break your problems into the smallest chunks possible and try to fix this small chunk.

Comment: I have already tried the approach of using a separate context to do the compositing. but it seems that having a separate canvas drops performance down to 1 frame. is there a way to have a separate context on the same canvas?. You keep telling me to read but that is not the issue. I am very well suited when it comes to programming. I'm not into watching tutorials I am trying to learn myself.

Comment: I am telling you to split your problem into smaller chunks that you can solve one by one. Having a second context should not make your FPS drop to 1 no, you are doing *something wrong*™. Your current problem has nothing to do with the Arrays you gave, nor even with tile-based game-engine implementation, it's all about how to colorize an image on a canvas and the web has lots of examples on how to do it. [Here is one using a second context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174195/how-to-re-tint-a-grayscale-image-on-canvas) (you need to create it only once, and it needs to be only 16x32px).

Answer (score 2):

I use 2d arrays, like so:

```
 var map = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],

]
```

An then i loop through all of the values in the map and set the fill style depending on the value.

```
for (y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {

            ctx.fillStyle = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"][map[y][x]];
            ctx.fillRect(x * tilesize, y * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);

        }
    }
```

And you can also use images instead of colors,

```
switch(map[x][y]){
case 1:
img = stone;
break;
case 2:
img = grass;
break;
 } 
ctx.fillImage(img,0,0,300,300,x*tilesize,y*tilesize,tilesize,tilesize);
```

Look up ctx.fillImage() for more info on those parameters.

Then the final program would look like this

```html
<canvas id="c" width=800 height=800></canvas>
<script>
  const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var tilesize = 10
  var map = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],

  ]

  function drawmap() {
    for (y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
      for (x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = ["red", "blue", "cyan", "yellow"][map[y][x]]
        ctx.fillRect(x * tilesize, y * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize)
      }
    }
  }

  drawmap()
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<img id="stone" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
q=tbn:ANd9GcTFYnQ2tB7R4YVGtOquPzZxc2fq_taDOYryug&usqp=CAU" style="display:none;">
<img id="grass" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
q=tbn:ANd9GcTFYnQ2tB7R4YVGtOquPzZxc2fq_taDOYryug&usqp=CAU" style="display:none;">
<canvas id="c" width=800 height=800></canvas>
<script>
  const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var grass = document.getElementById("grass")
  var stone = document.getElementById("stone")

  var tilesize = 10
  var map = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],

  ]

  function drawmap() {
    for (y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
      for (x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {
        switch(map[y][x]){
        case 1:
        img = stone;
        break;
        case 2:
        img = grass;
        break;
       }
       ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,300,300,x*tilesize,y*tilesize,tilesize,tilesize);
      }
    }
  }
```

I know this is not exactly what you asked for,
but it is a very good and fast way to do this.